# JavaScript access unknown properties of object

Tags: javascript

**Situation:**

I have multiple JS-Objects with the same structure.

In all of those Objects there's a property called console.

I'd like to assign a value (the same value) to each of these properties.

Please find below the **structure** of my code:

```
NameOfMyObject = function() {

     return {

        actions: null,

        console: null,

        init: function() {}, 

        //object specific functions

    }
};
```

**My Problem:**

Currently I'm assigning the value manual, but I want do do it generic.

Code snippet

```
this.console = console;
this.actions.console = console;
this.fixtures.console = console;
```

How can I access the properties of my objects?

I hope I asked my question clear enough.

Comment: `this.console = this.actions.console = this.fixtures.console = console`

Comment: Could you provide working code? As it stands now, `this.actions.console = console;` will give an exception.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: This code is working. `init` is like a cunstructor.

Comment: @Chris Li I'd like to do something like this `object.property.console = console;`

Comment: `init` is an empty block. `console` is `null`, so you cannot assign properties to it. This code is not working as you have it in the question. At least some necessary code is missing from it.

Comment: you want to run init and assign values to the object?

Comment: Providing all my could would go beyond the scope. I tried to explain what the structure is like.

Comment: Is your question that you want multiple objects to share one property so that if it is changed via one object it is also reflected when looking via another object?

Comment: @Chris Li Yeah, but generic because currently I'm assigning it manual.

Comment: @trincot Yeah, that might explain it well.

Comment: sounds like you need to use prototype

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0" "="), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would share a property across objects:

```js
function MyClass() {};

MyClass.prototype.console = {}; // Define a "common" property on the prototype

var obj1 = new MyClass(); // Create two instances
var obj2 = new MyClass();

Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1).console.id = 13; // Assign a value once...
console.log(obj1.console.id); // ... and it exists on both instances
console.log(obj2.console.id);
```

The shared property is on the prototype object.

Instead of `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1)` you can of course use `MyClass.prototype`, since you know that `obj1` was created by `MyClass`. They give the same prototype object.

If your property always has an object as value and you don't need to replace that value, only *mutate* it by setting properties on that object, then you don't need to explicitly reference the prototype to set a new value.

So this works:

```js
function MyClass() {};

MyClass.prototype.console = {}; // Define a "common" property on the prototype

var obj1 = new MyClass(); // Create two instances
var obj2 = new MyClass();

obj1.console.id = 13; // Assign a value once... (getting console from the prototype)
console.log(obj1.console.id); // ... and it exists on both instances
console.log(obj2.console.id);
```

But if you change `console` itself, you'll be setting it on the instance, not on the prototype:

```js
function MyClass() {};

MyClass.prototype.console = {}; // Define a "common" property on the prototype

var obj1 = new MyClass(); // Create two instances
var obj2 = new MyClass();

obj1.console = { id: 13}; // Setting an instance property now
console.log(obj1.console.id); // ... and it does not exist on both instances
console.log(obj2.console.id); // == undefined
```

So if that kind of assignment should still work on the prototype, you need to use the first code block with `Object.getPrototypeOf` or `MyClass.prototype`.